# Compare two strings case-insensitive

Tags: string, assembly, nasm

I have this code:

```
section .data
   msg1 db "Equal"
   msg1Len equ $ -msg1

   msg2 db "Not equal"
   msg2Len equ $ -msg2

   str1 db "abcde"
   str1Len equ $-str1

   str2 db "abcde"
   str2Len equ $ -str2

section .text
   global _start

_start:
   mov esi,str1
   mov edi,str2
   mov ecx,str2Len+1
   cld
   repe cmpsb
   jecxz equal  ;jumps if equal
            ;if not equal
   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,msg2
   mov edx,msg2Len
   int 80h

   jmp exit

equal:
   mov eax,4
   mov ebx,1
   mov ecx,msg1
   mov edx,msg1Len
   int 80h

exit:
   mov eax,1
   mov ebx,0
   int 80h
```

What I'm trying to do is make it case-insensitive like "abcde" is still equal to "Abcde".
However, it is case-sensitive. How do you make it case-insensitive? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to convert the two strings into a common case, for example uppercase, and compare those. If you don't want to manipulate the strings beforehand, you can do it on the fly, by converting the current checked characters to a common case and comparing. Take a look at an ASCII chart to figure out what the difference between the two cases of characters are so you can convert one to the other.

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking about that but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: i dont know how to make it to uppercase. :(

Comment: Look at the ASCII values of a character in the two different cases. What's the difference in decimal? What is the difference between them in binary?

Comment: Decimal conversion of 'a' is 65 while 'A' is 97. You have to add 32 to make it uppercase. How do you implement that?

Comment: How about using `add` instruction?